# How to use stopword elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, token

I have an Elasticsearch 1.5 running on my server,

specifically, I want/create three fields  with is

1.name

2.description

3.nickname

I want setup stopword for description and nickname field when I insert the data on the Elasticsearch then stop word automatically remove unwanted stopword. I'm trying so many time but not working.

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:9200/tryoindex/ -d'
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "custom_english_stemmer": {
          "type": "stemmer",
          "name": "english"
        },
        "snowball": {
          "type" : "snowball",
          "language" : "English"
                }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "custom_lowercase_stemmed": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "custom_english_stemmer",
            "snowball"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
    "_all" : {"enabled" : true},
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "custom_lowercase_stemmed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'

curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/tryoindex/nama/1" -d '{
  "text" : "Tryolabs running monkeys KANGAROOS and jumping elephants jum is your"
}'

curl "http://localhost:9200/tryoindex/nama/_search?pretty=1" -d '{
"query": {
    "query_string": {
        "query": "Tryolabs running monkeys KANGAROOS and jumping elephants jum is your",
        "fields": ["text"]
    }
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your analyzer part to

```
"analyzer": {
    "custom_lowercase_stemmed": {
      "tokenizer": "standard",
      "filter": [
        "stop",
        "lowercase",
        "custom_english_stemmer",
        "snowball"
      ]
    }
  }
```

To verify the changes use

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/tryoindex/_analyze?analyzer=custom_lowercase_stemmed' -d 'testing this is stopword testing'
```

and observe the tokens

```
{"tokens":[{"token":"test","start_offset":0,"end_offset":7,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":1},{"token":"stopword","start_offset":16,"end_offset":24,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":4},{"token":"test","start_offset":25,"end_offset":32,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":5}]}%
```

PS: If you don't want to get the stemmed version of testing, then remove the stemming filters.

Comment: still same, when open elasticsearch_plugin head and view the data, i can see stop word still exist...

Comment: maybe im in wrong idea about stop word ,  i already done the step you mention, and i got same token what you already got , but why the data still same as no word remove , stopword should remove the word rite? do you understand?

Comment: this and is are the stop words in english hence those got removed. Are you expecting something? In ES text will be converted to tokens and then the filters will be applied on these tokens, hence you will see no stop words and the stemmed version in the tokens, but actual text will be stored in _source field.

Comment: for example im insert sample data  "text" : "hi this me amir" , and im expected in ES the text change to  "text":"hi amir", is this can be done using stopword?

Comment: ES generates hi, me & amir as tokens. In ES text will be stored as one or more tokens depends on the analyzer, hence stop words will be removed from tokens. PS: if you want to add "me" to stop list follow http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/analysis-stop-tokenfilter.html.

Comment: maybe im still not fully understand how token work, do you mind give me anything about token stopword function?

Comment: Try these https://www.found.no/foundation/text-analysis-part-1/ https://www.found.no/foundation/text-analysis-part-2/

Comment: Also, source for the answer examples: [http://blog.tryolabs.com/2015/02/25/elasticsearch-analyzers-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-custom-filters/](http://blog.tryolabs.com/2015/02/25/elasticsearch-analyzers-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-custom-filters/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [stop token filter](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/analysis-stop-tokenfilter.html) in your analyzer filter chain.

Comment: what do you mean by chain?
this is what i want to do 
1.i want to insert this text into ES "testing this is stopword testing"
2.after insert , i want all stop word "this" "is" remove automatically and what left inside is "testing stopword testing", btw is this stopword token yang do?